# what standard container to pick (if any)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, containers

I need some memory management and was hoping I could base it on some `std` container. My requirements are:

1. elements have only a default constructor (no copy, no move, nothing else)
2. The container can be expanded (at the back) by a small contiguous block of elements
3. I even know roughly how many elements I will need in total, even better, at any time how many I will need eventually. These are estimates, though.
4. I don't really need an iterator, but a way to obtain the running number of an element would be handy.

So, I would need something that can be expanded by adding chunks, like `std::deque`. But with `std::deque`, I cannot guarantee that expansion by, say, 8 elements, gives me a contiguous block. And `std::deque` doesn't have `capacity` so I cannot 'adapt' from a `std::deque`.

This would mean that I have to write my own, correct? (*note: I don't want to know how to write my own, but only if I have to*).

**Edit** to clarify: only the blocks of elements obtained at each expansion has to be contiguous, but not the whole container -- that would obviously contradict with the other requirements.

**Edit for jalf** So what is this for: a spatial oct-tree for "sorting" 3D points. The tree nodes refer to cubic cells and form a linked structure with parents and daughters linked using pointers. Sibling nodes are not linked, but are adjacent in memory. The total number of nodes is not known in advance (because the number of points per final node >1), but an estimate can be obtained. During tree building, when dividing a non-final node, a contiguous chunk of up to 8 new nodes must be obtained and will then be linked into the tree. Moving or copying those nodes would invalidated any existing links (pointers) to them.

**Another Edit** Just to clarify some discussions. Any design that is based on `std::vector<T>` must not use `resize()` and/or `reserve()`. Both would require copy or move constructor of `T` under certain conditions. Even if never called under these conditions, the code won't compile.

Comment: For #2, are you saying that only the "new" elements have to be contiguous? If you have a container with 10 elements, and expand it to size 14, only the last 4 have to be contiguous?

Comment: You can't have contiguous, expandable, and no copying. Pick two.

Comment: `list<vector<T>>`? (With careful use of `reserve` on the vectors.)

Comment: Contiguous without copying is impossible unless you use a memory map and write your own memory manager. You will then also need to handle alignment, which means that you probable need single-byte alignment, which is pretty slow. I would use and use myself linked lists. For more static types, I simple inherit and extend structures and use a reflection library.

Comment: @jalf yes, only the new elements have to be contiguous.

Comment: @AlanStokes I never asked for a contiguous container.

Comment: @JensMunk see edit and my other comments.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this is for? Your requirements are pretty unusual, and I'm curious. :)

Comment: In that case, I think I would define a structure wrapping a std::container, e.g. vector. The outer structure should contain a size member, since you probably do not need the individual elements to be resizeable. The total capacity is then simple the sum. This is very reminiscent to how you design a file format with a header describing the offsets and size of individual chunks. I can recommend using HPF5 if you need a flexible file format with compression

Comment: Consider using boost::adjacency_list. It can be made compact, with tree-like structure and the only algorithm you need to devise is proper spatial lookup.

Comment: @Fiktik too much hassle. I have the code already in place, but some use some very dodgy ooold (C-style) memory management for the nodes. I just want to replace that with something proper.

Comment: @AlanStokes Sorry, `list<vector<T>>` cannot work: `std::vector::reserve` requires copy-constructible elements. so this won't compile, even though I will never call `reserve()` for a `vector` containing any elements.

Comment: @Walter: `vector::reserve` has no requirements on the elements.  Maybe you're thinking of `resize`?  Even so, `resize` only requires movable now, not copiable.  Are your items movable?

Comment: @Mooing I hate to argue against myself, but `reserve` must require either copyable or movable elements, or it can't possibly work if called on a non-empty vector with a target capacity greater than the current capacity.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Er, yes, right.  My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer appears to be *no single standard container does the job, you have to write your own*.

This proved to be more difficult than I thought due to the restriction that pointers to generated objects must remain valid for the lifetime of the memory manager (implemented in the original question by the request that objects cannot moved or copied). This excludes the use of `std::vector::resize()` and `std::vector::reserve()`. A `sequence_container<std::vector<T>>` design is still possible, but either requires to create another `vector` for each block of new objects or to pre-construct a whole chunk of objects and then give them out until the chunk is exhausted.

To avoid that, it seems one must write some `chunk` class (to use instead of `vector`) and deal with the `allocator` issues. Here is an implementation:

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>

template<typename type, typename allocator=std::allocator<type>,
         template<typename,typename> class sequence_container = std::list>
class chunk_allocator
{
public:
  using object = type;
  using pointer = object*;
  using size_type = std::size_t;
  using alloc_traits = std::allocator_traits<allocator>;
private:
  struct chunk
  {
    allocator alloc;
    const pointer beg_data, end_capacity;
    pointer end_data;
    chunk(size_type cap, const allocator&all)
      : alloc(all)
      , beg_data(alloc_traits::allocate(alloc,cap))
      , end_capacity(beg_data+cap)
      , end_data(beg_data) {}
    ~chunk()
    {
      if(beg_data==nullptr) return;
      for(; --end_data>=beg_data; --end_data)
        alloc_traits::destroy(alloc,end_data);
      alloc_traits::deallocate(alloc,beg_data,capacity());
    }
    size_type size() const noexcept { return end_data - beg_data; }
    size_type capacity() const noexcept { return end_capacity - beg_data; }
    pointer make(size_type n)
    {
      if(end_data + n > end_capacity)
        return nullptr;
      auto ptr = end_data;
      for(; n; --n,++end_data)
        alloc_traits::construct(alloc,end_data);
      return ptr;
    }
  };
  using chunk_alloc = typename alloc_traits::template rebind_alloc<chunk>;
  using chunk_container = sequence_container<chunk,chunk_alloc>;
  using chunk_iterator = typename chunk_container::iterator;
  chunk_container chunks;
  chunk_iterator last_chunk;
  /// no default constructor
  chunk_allocator() = delete;
  /// no copy
  chunk_allocator(chunk_allocator const&) = delete;
  chunk_allocator&operator=(chunk_allocator const&) = delete;
public:
  /// allow move
  chunk_allocator(chunk_allocator&&) = default;
  chunk_allocator&operator=(chunk_allocator&&) = default;
  /// constructor
  explicit
  chunk_allocator(size_type initial_capacity, allocator const&alloc=allocator())
    : chunks(alloc)
    , last_chunk(chunks.emplace(chunks.end(),initial_capacity,alloc)) {}
  /// invalid index
  static constexpr size_type invalid = ~size_type(0);
  /// find index for element, return invalid if not ours
  size_type index(const object*ptr) const noexcept
  {
    size_type n=0;
    for(auto c=chunks.begin(); c!=chunks.end(); ++c)
      if(c->beg_data <= ptr && ptr < c->end_data)
        return n + size_type(ptr-c->beg_data);
      else
        n += c->size();
    return invalid;
  }
  /// obtain contiguous chunks of objects
  /// \param[in] n          \# objects in returned chunk
  /// \param[in] chunk_size \# objects to allocate should we not have enough
  /// \return pointer to first of n contiguous objects
  object*create(const size_type n, size_type chunk_size=0)
  {
    if(n==0)
      return nullptr;
    if(last_chunk->end_data + n > last_chunk->end_capacity) {
      if(chunk_size==0) chunk_size = last_chunk->capacity();
      if(chunk_size< n) chunk_size = n;
      last_chunk = chunks.emplace(chunks.end(),chunk_size,last_chunk->alloc);
    }
    return last_chunk->make(n);
  }
};

// test
#include <iostream>
struct foo
{
  int X;
  static int C;
  foo() : X(C++) { std::cout<<"foo::foo(): X="<<X<<std::endl; }
  foo(foo const&) = delete;
  foo&operator=(foo const&) = delete;
  foo(foo &&) = delete;
  foo&operator=(foo &&) = delete;
};

int foo::C=0;
int main()
{
  std::cout<<" chunk_allocator<foo> C(3);"<<std::endl;
  chunk_allocator<foo> C(3);
  auto a = C.create(1);
  std::cout<<" auto a=C.create(1)="<<a<<std::endl;
  auto b = C.create(4);
  std::cout<<" auto b=C.create(4)="<<b<<std::endl;
  auto c = C.create(3);
  std::cout<<" auto c=C.create(3)="<<c<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<" a="<<a<<" a->X="<<a->X<<" index(a)="<<C.index(a)<<'\n'
       <<" b="<<b<<" b->X="<<b->X<<" index(b)="<<C.index(b)<<'\n'
       <<" c="<<c<<" c->X="<<c->X<<" index(c)="<<C.index(c)<<'\n';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With one catch, `std::vector` is for you.

It is entirely contiguous, not just in blocks, and can be expanded, remaining contiguous (point 2). Expansion may mean reallocation (therefore invalidation of previously obtained pointers/iterators, and *moving*), but if you know the total size in advance (point 3), you can `reserve()` so that no reallocation takes place.

Given an iterator `i` of vector `v`, you can obtain a running number (position) by `i - v.begin()`; similarly, given a pointer `p` to an element, by `p - &v[0]` (point 4).

The catch is your point 1. There is `emplace_back()`, but for reasons related exception safety, `std::vector` still attempts to temporarily construct elements somewhere and then *move* them to their permanent position.

Assuming you have this class

```
struct A
{
    A() { }
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A(const A&) = delete;
};
```

I can see two workarounds:

1. Derive another class `B` that default-constructs instead of copy/move-constructing:

   ```
   struct B : A
   {
       B() : A() { }
       B(B&&) : A() { }
       B(const B&) : A() { }
   };
   ```
2. If you can't do that, then make an allocator object that does this for you:

   ```
   template<typename T>
   struct allocator : std::allocator<T>
   {
       using std::allocator<T>::allocator;
       using std::allocator<T>::construct;

       template<typename U>
       void construct(U* p, U&&) { construct(p); }

       template<typename U>
       void construct(U* p, const U&) { construct(p); }

       template<typename U>
       struct rebind { using other = allocator<U>; };
   };

   template<>
   struct allocator<void> : std::allocator<void> { };
   ```

The use of both cases is illustrated below ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36472e752f2a1bab)):

```
template<typename C, size_t N = 100>
void test()
{
    C c;
    c.reserve(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        c.emplace_back();
}

int main ()
{
    test<std::vector<B> >();
    test<std::vector<A, allocator <A> > >();
}
```

Keep in mind that this way there are still instances of `A` that are constructed then thrown away. This is an unfortunate consequence of using `std::vector`. If `A` is small enough and its default-construction does not have any weird side-effects, this should not be a problem.

If you still need expansion beyond the initial `reserve()`, then I suggest a container of such vectors to be used as blocks. And if you still want to view this meta-container as a single container with its own iterator, then relevant is my own [`join` view](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/view/join.hpp) and its [iterator](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/iter/join.hpp) just for an idea, but this is still very experimental. I bet there's something for this purpose in Boost as well, but I'm not so familiar.

Comment: I don't like that, because I want to avoid the costs of re-sizing (required if capacity was too small).

Comment: Fair enough, but measure first. My last suggestion stands: make another container the contains vectors as blocks, as outlined above. This can be easy or hard (or very hard) depending on other requirements (e.g. if you want to have iterators, random access etc.).

Comment: It turns out that even with copying, `std::vector` outperforms almost everything else because it is very cache friendly (where `std::list` is cache hostile, and `std::deque` isn't much better than `std::list`) and generally allocates memory less often than the alternatives.  You really want to profile before declaring `std::vector` too slow.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise simply using a `std::deque<std::vector<T>>` as a private data member of a custom class that ensures that:

- new elements are only added at the back
- the elements are added in chunks

Comment: I thought about a design using `std::list<std::vector<T>>`.

Comment: `deque` has Random Access, whereas `list` does not; `deque` is also more compact (in memory). In your situation, it's just strictly better.

Comment: It's more compact, but has all those (initially empty) vectors on the heap. I may only need a few vectors, perhaps only one (if my initial guess for the number of nodes was ok).

Comment: @Walter: An empty vector should be only 24 bytes worth (on 64 bits platforms), however if you are comfortable with a `list`, go ahead.

Comment: I just tried to implement this using the `sequence_container<std::vector<T>>` design, but stumbled over the issue that `std::vector::reserve()` requires copy-constructible elements ... So I cannot use `reserve()` -- what shall I do instead?

Comment: What? `resize` has the same problem: it requires copy of existing elements if new_size > `capacity()`. The fact that I will never call it in this situation is irrelevant here: the code will not compile.

Comment: @Walter: yes indeed, sorry, you need to use the constructor directly. Use [the 3rd overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector): `vector(size_type count);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple templated C++11 class which uses a vector of pointers to vectors to contain elements, it is extended at the back in chunks.  Pointers to previously allocated elements remain valid after an extension.  It supports range based for loops and random access.  I use std::vector for two purposes, one top level vector to keep pointers to the 2nd level vectors, the top vector is expanded with normal push_back, so the pointers to the 2nd level vectors get copied (very fast) every time you reach a power of 2 of number of extensions - which are specified to be very few and infrequent. The 2nd level vectors are allocated with an initial size given at time of construction of the Chunky instance or during extend and the size is never changed, they contain the elements (parameter to the template) and therefore pointers to the elements are not invalidated by a call to extend().

I timed 10 extensions of 1 million elements each and an access to each of them, it ran in 106 milliseconds (10.6 nanoseconds per access average).

([coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a54878d0aad705aa))

I then timed 1000 extensions of 10,000 elements each and an access to each of them, it ran in 115 milliseconds (11.5 nanoseconds per access average).

([coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/891806bd56bd577b))

chunky.h

```
#ifndef CHUNKY_H
#define CHUNKY_H
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>

template<class T> class Chunky {
    std::vector< std::vector<T> * > _chunk;
    size_t _size   = 0;
    T*     _active = nullptr;
    size_t _begin  = 0;
    size_t _end    = 0;
 public:
    Chunky() = default;
    Chunky( size_t guess ) { extend( guess ); }
    ~Chunky() { for ( auto & it : _chunk ) delete it; }
    void extend( size_t x ) {
        _chunk.push_back( new std::vector<T>( x ) );
        _size += x;
    }
    size_t size() const { return _size; }
    T & operator[]( size_t z ) { return at( z ); }
    T & at( size_t z ) {
        if ( z < _begin || z >= _end ) {
            size_t x = 0;
            for( _end = 0; z >= _end && x < _chunk.size(); ++x)
            {
                _begin = _end;
                _end += _chunk[x]->size();
                _active = _chunk[x]->data();
            }
            if (z >= _end) throw std::out_of_range("Chunky at "+std::to_string(z));
        }
        return _active[z - _begin];
    }
    class iterator
    : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, int>
    {
        Chunky<T> * _tp = nullptr;
        size_t _x = 0;
    public:
        iterator() = default;
        iterator(Chunky<T> * tp) : _tp(tp) {}
        bool operator!= (const iterator& other) const {
            return _tp != other._tp || _x != other._x;
        }
        T & operator* () const { return _tp->at(_x); }
        T * operator->() const { return &_tp->at(_x); }
        iterator& operator++ () {
            if (++_x >= _tp->size()) {
                _x = 0;
                _tp = nullptr;
            }
            return *this;
        }
        iterator& operator+= ( size_t x ) { while(x--) *this++; return *this; }
        friend inline iterator& operator+ ( iterator & lhs, size_t x ) { while(x--) ++lhs; return lhs; }
        friend inline iterator operator+ ( iterator lhs, size_t x ) { while(x--) ++lhs; return lhs; }
    };
    inline iterator begin() { return iterator(this); }
    static inline const iterator end() { return iterator(); }

};

#endif
```

A simple test

```
#include "chunky.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using std::chrono::steady_clock;

struct Element
{
    int _value = 0;
    Element() = default;
    Element(const Element&) = delete;
    Element(Element&&) = delete;
    Element& operator=(Element const&) = delete;
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    Chunky<Element> c( 5 ); // 5 default constructed Elements
    int i = 0;    

    // Chunky allows range based for loop
    for( auto & it : c ) it._value = 100 + i++;

    // Pointers to elements are valid for the lifetime of the container
    Element * element_ptr = & c[4]; // Take address of one of the elements
    std::cout << "The fifth element has a value of " << element_ptr->_value << std::endl;

    size_t previous_size = c.size();

    c.extend( 10 ); // 10 more default constructed Elements

    std::cout << "Dereferencing pointer to fifth element after extend, value is still " << element_ptr->_value << std::endl;

    for( size_t k=0; k < 10; ++k )
        c[previous_size + k]._value = 1100 + i++;

    // random access to initial elements and newly extended elements
    c[3]._value = -3;
    c[13]._value = -13;

    std::cout << "\nThe Elements contain values of: " << std::endl;

    // range based for loop
    for( auto & it : c ) std::cout << it._value << std::endl;

    steady_clock::time_point start = steady_clock::now();

    size_t extend_size = 1e6;

    for( size_t x = 0; x < 10; ++x ) {
        size_t previous_size = c.size();
        c.extend( extend_size ); // 1 million more default constructed Elements
        for( size_t k=0; k < extend_size; ++k )
            c[previous_size + k]._value = previous_size + k;
    }

    steady_clock::time_point end = steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "\nExtending 10 times by " << extend_size << " and initializing the Elements took "
        << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count()
        << " msec.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Example run

```
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
The fifth element has a value of 104
Dereferencing pointer to fifth element after extend, value is still 104

The Elements contain values of: 
100
101
102
-3
104
1105
1106
1107
1108
1109
1110
1111
1112
-13
1114

Extending 10 times by 1000000 and initializing the Elements took 106 msec.
```

Comment: What I want is essentially an allocator which avoids calling `new` everytime I need some memory. However, your implementation does exactly that: calling new every time `extend()` is called.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid many calls to `new`. Also, copying my objects (needed if they were in an expandable vector), breaks my code. `std::deque` would be perfect, if I could get a contiguous chunk of objects from it.

Comment: @Walter, I understand.  I should point out that I'm not using an expandable vector.  I construct vectors once, with the size given to the `extend` member function, and they are not destructed until the `Chunky` instance is destructed.  The `Element` class has deleted the copy constructor, the move constructor, and the assignment operator.  Give it a try.

Comment: @Walter I should clarify, I use std::vector for two purposes, one top level vector to keep pointers to the 2nd level vectors, the top vector is expanded with normal push_back, so the pointers to the 2nd level vectors get copied (very fast) every time you reach a power of 2 of number of extensions (which you said are very few and infrequent).  The 2nd level vectors are allocated with an initial size and the size is never changed, they contain the elements (parameter to the template) and therefore pointers to the elements are not invalidated by a call to `extend()`.

Comment: you could as well directly allocated from the heap each time. That's what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

What's with all the complicated solutions? Won't `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` solve the problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: That would work, at the expense of a pointer per Element and possibly poor spatial locality of the Elements themselves, depending on the allocator used for them.  I think the OP wants contiguous Elements for the most part and probably doesn't want 8 bytes (a unique_ptr) per Element.

Comment: another issue is that one cannot provide a custom allocator (at least not easily ... and the correspondinc deleter)